# Calling psutil.Process() fails when used inside of Docker container on Jenkins

Tags: python, linux, docker, jenkins

When running `psutil.Process()` in Docker, while using Jenkins runner, I get `psutil.NoSuchProcess: process PID not found` error, the whole error trace is below.

The interesting thing is that this works in Docker/Podman outside of Jenkins runner (tested with various versions of both Docker and Podman on Linux/Windows/MacOS) and it also works with different versions of `psutil` package. I always used Debian based docker images (python:3.11.7-bookworm and similar).

The only situation where I consistently have this error is in Jenkins pipeline.

Python script used for testing is just this:

```
import psutil

p = psutil.Process()
```

An example of Jenkinsfile where this is tested is the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'Linux'
    }
    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '''
                        podman run -dit --name test --rm docker_image
                        podman exec -it test /bin/bash -c "python test.py"
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the complete error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 1643, in wrapper
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_common.py", line 486, in wrapper
    raise raise_from(err, None)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_common.py", line 484, in wrapper
    return fun(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 1705, in _parse_stat_file
    data = bcat("%s/%s/stat" % (self._procfs_path, self.pid))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_common.py", line 820, in bcat
    return cat(fname, fallback=fallback, _open=open_binary)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_common.py", line 808, in cat
    with _open(fname) as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_common.py", line 772, in open_binary
    return open(fname, "rb", buffering=FILE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/2/stat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 350, in _init
    self.create_time()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 735, in create_time
    self._create_time = self._proc.create_time()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 1643, in wrapper
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 1870, in create_time
    ctime = float(self._parse_stat_file()['create_time'])
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 1652, in wrapper
    raise NoSuchProcess(self.pid, self._name)
psutil.NoSuchProcess: process no longer exists (pid=2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    p = psutil.Process()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 313, in __init__
    self._init(pid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 362, in _init
    raise NoSuchProcess(pid, msg='process PID not found')
psutil.NoSuchProcess: process PID not found (pid=2)
```

Comment: What's your actual goal with this setup?  I'd normally expect the container process namespace to only contain the main container process, as pid 1; using the `docker exec` debugging tool to list the processes in the container doesn't seem like it'd be fruitful.

Comment: My goal isn't related to psutil at all, I'm using terraform in Docker to create Azure infrastructure, and as a part of that I have a few Python scripts. Each one of them contains import of Azure MLClient from azure-ai-ml, and that import calls psutil.Process() which then crashes the whole pipeline.

Comment: Can you successfully `docker run` them as independent containers?

Comment: I can't, they fail regardless.